# What does “we tend to squirm” mean in this situation?

Tags: phrase-usage

What does the last part of this sentence mean?

> When we talk about money, **we tend to squirm.**
> <sub>Source: tweet visible on [bottradionetwork.com](http://www.bottradionetwork.com/2014/09/when-we-talk-about-money-we-tend-to-squirm-alis/)</sub>

Does it have other use cases?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! You can read "squirm" as "feel embarrassed". Also, you can find more info about the word in most online dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few subtle things going on with this sentence.

First, the author is using "we" a lot.  This tells us that the author is speaking of himself and the reader.  The author feels like the opinion is popular enough that it is safe to assume people will agree.

The second interesting part is "we tend to".  This means that it is more likely to be true than not.  For instance, when I buy a hamburger, I tend to buy french fries as well.  "Tend to" also implies that it is not a complete certainty, and there will be exceptions - I enjoy a burger without french fries sometimes as well.

The last part is "squirm", which means to move in a twisty manner, like a worm found under a rock.  This is similar to the way a child might move if embarrassed, and there is a childish feel to this word.  Someone who "squirms" is probably not in control of the situation and at a loss as to what to do - for instance, a criminal on trial might squirm when caught in a lie.

Put together, the author is saying that almost all of us feel uncomfortable and at a loss when we talk about money.